# Strange zsh startup command with "uh oh" spam

Tags: macos, mac, terminal, zsh

I am currently on macOS Sonoma 14.2 (Beta) and have a MacBook Pro 2021 with an M1 Max.

I genuinely have no idea where to start on this problem. Whenever I open up a Terminal, I get this weird spammy output.

[image]

It keeps spamming this and will not terminate, and I can't find anything online to help me stop this.

I have no clue where to start and how to stop this. I use the Terminal quite frequently and desperately need this fixed!

PS: This problem also occurs when using the Terminal through applications like Visual Studio Code.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 Thank you so much! I checked my zshrc and for some reason it was running the yes command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That `[1] 19620` indicates that whatever is happening it was launched as a background process with the process ID of 19620. That number most likely changes with each launch of the Terminal.

I would recommend going into “Applications > Utilities” and launching “Activity Monitor” and then launch Terminal and see if there is a process ID that matches what you see in the terminal.

Then when you spot the process, kill the process by selecting it and clicking the small “x” in the upper left and that should be that; the “uh oh” stuff should stop.

After that’s done, I recommend you check your `~/.zshrc` and other files to try and find the shell script causing it and getting rid of it.